# Логи коннектов к MySQL на удаленном сервере

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

На сервере с ubuntu 14.04 был открыт 3306 порт MySQL для миграции сайта. Проблема в том что мигрировали давно, а порт был открыт наружу длительное время. Можно ли проверить (найти в логах) кто пытался подключиться к mysql и/или успешные коннекты? Хочется понять, не воспользовался ли кто-нибудь открытым портом.